# Update Database leads to "Invalid account ID or license key" message

Tags: geoip

I'm running the geoipupdate tool (https://github.com/maxmind/geoipupdate) to update the database.
If I run it locally, it works well.
When I use it on my prod server, I get the "Invalid account ID or license key" message.
My account ID and licence key are correct, as it is working on my computer.
Do you have any idea why it bugs?
Thanks a lot!

Matthieu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it was the download that was blocked from the server. So when I had authorization to perform downloads from the server, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation asks you to create conf a file in a path '/usr/local/etc/GeoIP.conf'. It can be confusing.

For example, ubuntu path is: '/etc/GeoIP.conf'

Check your path:

> $ geoipupdate -h